# System Verilog Nested Associative Array

Tags: associative-array, system-verilog

How do you declare and initialize a nested associative array in SystemVerilog?

```
/*
  Creating an associative array(AA) called timings such that
  each key contains an AA with a list of relevant key value pairs
*/
typedef string timingObj [string];
timingObj timings [string] = {"A": {"B" : "C"}, "X": {"Y" : "Z"} };
//string timings [timingObj] = {"A": {"B" : "C"}, "X": {"Y" : "Z"} }; //Same error

timingObj t;
$cast(t, timings["A"]); // t = {"B" : "C"}
$display("%s", timings["A"]);
$display("%s", t["B"]);
```

The code above results in compiler errors:

```
"Syntax error. Unexpected token: }. Expected tokens: ':'." "testbench.sv" 2
"Syntax error. Unexpected token: $cast[_SYSTEM_CAST]. Expected tokens: ';' , 'checker' , 'function' , 'task' , 'timeprecision' ... ." "testbench.sv" 6  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment patterns for associative arrays need a `'{}` mark in front to distinguish it from a concatenation `{}`. There are some cases where it is ambiguous (but not here). So write

```
timingObj timings [string] = '{"A": '{"B" : "C"}, "X": '{"Y" : "Z"} };
```

Comment: Good thing i cleaned the code a bit, then how would you access each individual key? the $cast function returns an error, is it even required?

Comment: `$cast` is only needed for certain class variable assignments and when you are not sure of the variable type because of type parameterization. You should be able to write `t = timings["A"];`

Comment: and finally.... `$display("%s", t["B"]);` to access the nested variable?

Comment: `timings["A"]` is not a string, is an associative array of strings. Use `%p` instead of `%s`

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, `t = timings["A"];$display("%p", t["B"]);` displaying "C" but instead it returns a new error "Syntax error. Unexpected token: t[_IDENTIFIER] ..."

Comment: You should post this as a separate question with a complete example.